# Why won't my Ansible module return the correct result

Tags: python, ansible

I'm working on my first Ansible module and I decided to automate a simple task I had a bash script for.  This module looks at the kernel running vs kernel installed and lets me know to reboot in the case there is a mismatch.  I've tested the code sans Ansible stuff and it should work, but the code always returns true (even if I swap the != with ==):

```
import os

def main():
        module = AnsibleModule(
                argument_spec = dict()
        )

        (rc, uname_os, stderr) = module.run_command("uname -r")
        (rc, rpm_os, stderr) = module.run_command("rpm -q --last kernel | perl -pe 's/^kernel-(\S+).*/$1/' | head -1 | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//' | sed 's/ //g'")

        if rpm_os.rstrip() != uname_os.rstrip():
                out = "REBOOT"
                changed = True     ## now changed is changed to True
        else:   
                out = "DO NOT REBOOT"
                changed = False

        module.exit_json(changed=changed, output=out)

from ansible.module_utils.basic import *
main()
```

I don't expect to take any args (well I don't think I do).  Can someone give me some hints on what I'm doing wrong here?

**UPDATE**

I modified the basic logic flaw per that was pointed out.  I'm still getting the != condition all the time even though I've tested against two machines that I know should A) REBOOT B) DO NOT REBOOT.  I thought perhaps the string had extra characters so I tried stripping them.  However, testing using OS I see this:

```
>>> import os
>>> a = os.system("uname -r")
2.6.18-406.el5.centos.plus
>>> b = os.system("rpm -q --last kernel | perl -pe 's/^kernel-(\S+).*/$1/' | head -1 | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//' | sed 's/ //g'")
2.6.18-406.el5.centos.plus
>>> a == b
True
>>>
```

So I would expect the same behavior in module.run_command().  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

changed = False is always the last statement executed whether rpm_os !=  (or ==) uname_os --> as is "out =" and "module.exit" which you possibly don't want here either.  I assume you return "changed" and not some other variable from the function.  Try:

```
    changed = False   ## default
    out = "DO NOT REBOOT"
    if rpm_os != uname_os:
            out = "REBOOT"
            changed = True     ## now changed is changed to True
    module.exit_json(changed=changed, output=out)
```

Comment: I hate when I miss obvious stuff like that. I got so caught up in the Ansible portion, I missed the basic logic failure. Thanks!